# Callback error when contract is mined successfully

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I am getting an error today, when tried to mine a contract to ethereum testnet. Even after the transaction is mined successfully (I can check that in the Testnet), the call back is executing the code inside the error.

The callback function in my java script as follows:

```
function mine_pContract(byteCode, abi, estimatedGas) {
console.log(abi);
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));

var myContractReturned = MyContract.new({
    from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
    data: byteCode,
    gas:estimatedGas}, function(err, myContract) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while mining the contract" + err)
    }
    else {
        if (!myContract) {
            console.log("Contract transaction sent. Transaction Hash" + myContract.transactionHash + "waiting to be mined");
        }
        else {
            if (myContract.address === undefined) {
                console.log("still mining. Transaction Hash= " + myContract.transactionHash)
            }
            else {
                console.log("Contract mined. Address" + myContract.address);
            }
        }
    }
  });
}
```

The output is:
still mining. Transaction Hash= 0x859cbff73bf7da136f1b5402f1d9a7948608d6ef82c9e5f956db3e576fa5d720
main.js:262

Error while mining the contractError: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.

But it was supposed to showthe following message
Contract mined. Address: 0xxxxxxxx.

Any one can point out where is the problem?

Comment: The obvious problem would be that you're not sending enough gas. How are you setting the estimatedGas variable?

Comment: I am just passing a value from my HTML.... I tried with pretty high amounts (600000 - 1000000). It doesn't seems to be a problem with gas amount. The transaction are mined successfully if I track through the ropsten ui (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x859cbff73bf7da136f1b5402f1d9a7948608d6ef82c9e5f956db3e576fa5d720). But, in the callback it is returning error before mining. The same code in fact work for me before (1 week). It's not working from today. Is it because of some network delay or something else?

Comment: Can you share the constructor function of your contract?

Comment: t's the most basic contract. The code is as follows: 

pragma solidity ^0.4.0; 


contract Patient { 

string public swarmHashP = "76565ef4c1609f619e57f97956454b0b78c1e0b1067677f26839b3dc565‌​67a56465"; 

function changeLocation(string _newSwarmHashP) { 

swarmHashP = _newSwarmHashP; 

}

}

Answer (score 0):

```
                contract = this.web3.eth.contract(abi);
                contract.new(Params.toString(), {
                    from: this.web3.eth.defaultAccount,
                    data: code,
                    gas: estimatedGas
                }, (error, contractInst) => {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else if(contractInst.address){
                        console.log(contractInst);
                    }
                });
```

This is how I am using mined contract in my Dapp. Try to make correction followed by my example and hope it will work.

For more info check https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract